# ¿Por qué me aparece este error en Delphi? En ButtonDot.Caption

Tags: delphi, pascal

Este es el código:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonDotClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (POS('.', txtResult.Text))<>0 then
  exit
  else
  txtResult.Text := txtResult.Text + ButtonDot.Caption;

end;
```

El error que aparece es el siguiente: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Caption'

Comment: No sobra revisar si en la sección `var` está definido `ButtonDot`.

Comment: Creo que no es necesario que esté definido en la sección var. Como tal es un botón, por lo que tratarlo como una variable, ¿No sería del todo correcto no?

Comment: En este caso el error es claro: "El compilador no conoce Caption". Dependiendo de cómo esté definido el objeto ButtonDot el problema es que no posee ninguna propiedad con ese nombre.
Para saber más, es necesario conocer ¿Qué es y de qué tipo es ButtonDot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré el error.

En Delphi tenemos la opción de crear un archivo que sea VCL de Windows o un Multi-Device, siendo para todas las plataformas este último.

En el caso de crear un archivo VCL, el programa sí conoce la extensión .Caption, pero en el caso de usar un Multi-Device la extensión .Caption ha de sustituirse por .Text.

En este caso el error desaparece.

Comment: Delphi trabaja con 2 frameworks de componentes; VCL (Sólo para Windows) y FMX (Multiplataforma -Windows, Androis, iOS, macOS-)

La solución a tu problema no pasa por cambiar de framework, sino por usar la propiedad correcta en cada caso. Como bien dices, en uno se usa Caption y en otro se usa Text.

Cambiar de Framework tiene muuuuuchas repercusiones y no se reduce a algo tan simple como hacerlo todo el FMX (porque el multiplataforma). Para muchas cosas es mejor y más recomendable utilizar VCL.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación!